# How to redirect all my website posts/pages from Http (+ www or non-www) to Https (non-www) URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, https

I recently updated my website from http to HTTPS & I don't have any prior knowledge about this. I did it following some articles on the internet & it was successful. My site is accessible through https & it's all fine.

But I'm stuck with redirecting the existing pages and posts. I'm not sure if I messed it up or I just don't know how to redirect properly.

Here's what I'm trying to do, I want to redirect all the URLs in the below format to redirect

**from:**

- http://example.com/*
- http://www.example.com/*
- https://www.example.com/*

**to**

- https://example.com/*

I've tried using the following code, but it's not helping.

```
# Canonical https/www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after carefully doing some troubleshooting. The issue is with ReallySimple SSL plugin I used while updating to https.

By default, the plugin is redirecting all the traffic to https://www.example.com format which is showing an error page.

So I made the changes as per my requirement.

The problem is I didn't notice that this code exists & I'm looking at a wrong htaccess file in root folder instead of the htaccess file in public_html file.

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.1]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this is helpful if someone faces similar issue.